# Cocoa Binding Mutable Dictionary with Search Field

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

In my header file, I have a property declared

```
@property (strong) NSMutableDictionary *myContents;
```

In my implementation, I have assigned the contents of a plist (which are dictonaries) to the NSMutableDictionary.

In my window, I have a NSSearchField that I would like to bind with the Dictionary and that is the problem. I have a few questions and still don't understand after reasearching.

(1)Which should I use? NSObjectController, NSDictonaryController, or NSTreeController.

(2)How should I bind the controller to the dictionary? Is there a "key" and a "value" that I can bind or do I have to use properties declared in another class and add it to the dictionary?

(3)Can I bind that into a NSTableView with a "Key" on one side and a "value" on another side?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
My plist is like this Dictonary(root)>Dictionary>Strings. The way I set up my dictionary is like this:

```
NSString *myListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Collection" ofType:@"plist"];
self.Dictionary1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myListPath];
```

And I access one of them by :

```
    NSString *initialString = [[_Dictionary1 valueForKey:@"Book1"]objectForKey:@"1"];
```

Book1 is a Dictionary(2nd one). "1" is the string and is a chapter of Book1. How do I split this up then?

Comment: You should go with NSObjectController. Right now I dont have mac with me, tomorrow I will give you full working application with steps :)

Comment: I hope till then you will solve the problem

Comment: +1 for question on osx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1)Which should I use? NSObjectController, NSDictonaryController, or
>   NSTreeController.

Use NSDictionaryController.

> (2)How should I bind the controller to the dictionary? Is there a
>   "key" and a "value" that I can bind or do I have to use properties
>   declared in another class and add it to the dictionary?

Step 1 : Create `@property(strong)NSMutableDictionary *dict;` in .h file

Step 2 : Create a NSDictionaryController.

Step 3 : Check prepares content.

Step 4 : Set as :

[image]

Step 5 : Create a NSTableView.

Step 6 : For first column do as:

[image]

Step 7 : similarly for second column put `value` in `Model Key Path`.

Find the [running sample here](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5940093/dictionarycontrollerwithsearchfield-35k?da=y).

> (3)Can I bind that into a NSTableView with a "Key" on one side and a
>   "value" on another side?

Already done.

**Binding NSDictionaryController with NSTableView by NSSearchField**

Step 1 : Draw a NSSearchField.

Step 2 : Bind it to NSDicitonaryController in Predicate option.

Step 3 : In predicate format put `key contains $value`

[image]

Comment: It is implemented, please check :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how to thank you but I still have a problem. I am so sorry but please help me. It is in the UPDATED section. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As your **Second Question** is :

> NSString *myListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
>   pathForResource:@"Collection" ofType:@"plist"]; self.Dictionary1 =
>   [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myListPath];
>
> And I
>   access one of them by :
>
> ```
> NSString *initialString = [[_Dictionary1 valueForKey:@"Book1"]objectForKey:@"1"];
> ```

You can use :

```
NSString *book=@"Book1";
NSString *chapter=[book integerValue];
NSString *initialString=self.Dictionary1[book][chapter];
```

Comment: Then how would I bind this to the Dictionary Contoller. I found out that Key is : Book and the value turned out to be : "1 = storystory". How do I solve this?