# Search Field Predicate Format

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, predicate, nssearchfield

I am having questions on using a NSSearchField. I binded it to my Dictionary Controller and now I would like to search from it. Here is the project

MyPlist(top)
[image: MyPlist]

My Header File(Bottom)

[image]

My Implementation:
[image]

My Interface
[image]

I have binded my Search to my NSDictionaryController using the following Predicate Format

```
key contains $value
```

**What I expect** : I search"One", "G1" and "One" comes out

**What I get** : I search "One", nothing comes out. When I search"G1", "G1" and "One" comes out.

How do I make it that I can search a value and get the key and value from it? Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274870/cocoa-binding-mutable-dictionary-with-search-field/15299385#15299385

Comment: that's mine!!! I used "key contains $value" and it doesn't do as I expected.

Comment: did you checked the running sample

Comment: yes, can I email you my version?

Comment: I compared the both but couldn't find any difference!

Comment: Try using `localizedKey` instead of `key`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25883/discussion-between-user1927992-and-anoop-vaidya)

Answer (score 2):

Binding NSDictionaryController with NSTableView by NSSearchField

Step 1 : Draw a NSSearchField.

Step 2 : Bind it to NSDicitonaryController in Predicate option.

Step 3 : In predicate format put key contains $value

Running Sample [here](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5940093/dictionarycontrollerwithsearchfield-35k?da=y)

Comment: I inspected the project and I found out that it "worked" was because your key contained the value itself inside it. I hoped it to be that I can search "One"(Value) and it will come out both the key and the value. It works when I search for the key but doesn't when I try to search for the value.

Comment: Please help me~ thank you Anoop!